# R: How to turn the values in a column into the number of rows?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, datatables, transpose

How do I turn
[this data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzzFv.jpg) into one that looks like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyKp8.jpg). Where the number of columns is equal to the available values in the month column, and the number of rows is equal to the years available. Thank you.

Comment: Please review how to post a [reproduicble example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can make a copy of your data we can use with `dput`. Do not post images - we cant copy paste from them and they dont work with screen readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base R way is less elegant, but here is an approach.

```
Result <- reshape(NYHSpot,direction = "wide",idvar="Year", timevar = "Month")
colnames(Result)[2:13] <- month.abb
Result
   Year   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1  1986 0.420 0.340 0.460 0.420 0.410 0.411 0.434    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
8  1987 0.557 0.556 0.523 0.518 0.541 0.516 0.454 0.489 0.474 0.509 0.504 0.542
20 1988    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 0.449 0.461 0.452    NA    NA
```

**Data**

```
NYHSpot <- structure(list(i..Spot.Price = c(0.42, 0.34, 0.46, 0.42, 0.41, 
0.411, 0.434, 0.489, 0.474, 0.509, 0.504, 0.542, 0.557, 0.556, 
0.523, 0.518, 0.541, 0.516, 0.454, 0.449, 0.461, 0.452), Month = c(6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Year = c(1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 
1986, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 
1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1988)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you don't have tidyr package installed, please install it first

```
install.packages("tidyr")
```

Then following codes will do what you want

```
library(tidyr)

# sample data
DF <- data.frame(Price = c(42,34,42,45,54,60), 
                 Month = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                 Year = c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001))

DF %>%
  mutate(Month = month.abb[Month]) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = Price)
```

Result:

```
   Year   Jan   Feb   Mar
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2000    42    34    42
2  2001    45    54    60
```

PS: for next time, please ask question in reproductible example. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for inspiration